# How to send a push notification request using XHR (Ajax)

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, curl

This is the command to make a request from the terminal, with cURL. It works! However, I have no idea how to make the same request via XHR (Ajax). Any help will be much appreciated.

```
curl --header "Authorization: key=ABC123" --header "Content-Type: application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send -d "{\"registration\_ids\":[\"DFG456\"]}"
```

Comment: Which programming language are you using on server-side? PHP?

Comment: Javascript? I'm using Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) and I'm using parse.com to host the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the PHP code (you need to have installed `php5-curl` package):

```
// curl.php
$data = ["registration_ids" => ["DFG456"]];
$dataString = json_encode($data);

$curl = curl_init('https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dataString);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: key=ABC123',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($dataString)
]);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
print_r($result);
```

and ajax request (using jquery):

```
// index.html
<button id="send">Send</button>
<script>
    $("#send").click(function() {
        $.get("curl.php", function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```